# How do I bring my containers to be visible? PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I had some containers that showed some graphic shapes and text on the screen but as soon as I put a background some of them disappeared while others were still there. I am guessing that the background overlapped some of them but I can't seems find a solution to bring them at the front. I tried the ".toGlobal" but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I solved it by adding the container children after the background.